# Calculating percentage of data left after removal of outliers gives output numeric(0)

Tags: r

I am trying to extract a column from a dataset and identify any outliers within this column. The goal is to display the percentage of the data left once any outliers are removed. The code is working until the very last line. For some reason, I am getting output: `numeric(0)` Does anybody know what the problem is? Below is my code. I think I need to calculate the percentage minus outliers using a different argument than `nrow` but am not sure what to do.

```
dep_delay<-flights$dep_delay
dep_delay_upper<-quantile(dep_delay,0.997,na.rm=TRUE)
dep_delay_lower<-quantile(dep_delay,0.003,na.rm=TRUE)
dep_delay_out<-which(dep_delay>dep_delay_upper|dep_delay<dep_delay_lower)
(nrow(dep_delay)-length(dep_delay_out))/nrow(dep_delay)*100
```

Comment: `dep_delay <- flights$delay` is initialized as a vector so `nrow(dep_delay)` will fail.  Try `length(dep_delay)`